# Windows - can't run "sfc /scannow", because another maintenance task is in progress

Tags: windows, windows-8, maintenance, sfc

I tried to fix a friends laptop by repairing corrupt system files with `sfc /scannow` but I always get a message saying something like "there is another maintenance in progress" please try it later. But this always shows even if I execute it directly after the reboot?

Why is this happening, how can I find out which maintenance task is blocking it?

Comment: Try this. Go to Control Panel > Security and Maintenance .... click on Maintenance to expand and under Automatic Maintenance click on Stop Maintenance.

Comment: SFC shouldn’t be used on Windows 8+ DISM should be used it’s more effective.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling it with `psexec`as descibed [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/automatic-maintenance-windows-8).

Download the [PSTools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) and run psexec to disable it (Otherwise even as admin you will get an access denied)

```
psexec -s schtasks /change /tn "\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Maintenance Configurator" /DISABLE
```

Comment: I will try it out as soon as I have to opportunity. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is old, but it might help others.  If you have Zone Alarm installed, hover over its icon to see its  status.  Uninstall if it says that it is “initializing” and it is taking forever. If that’s the case, Zone Alarm is most likely corrupted. Or just run DISM to restore health.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1113097)